# Custom ListView in Worklight using Dojo

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working on a Worklight project, and I am trying to use custom listview. I use the Dojo toolkit to implement it, but it's not coming up to my expectations. Regarding design I am confuse. Here is my code:

```
<div id="bookmarks" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView">
    <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Heading">Some Heading</h1>

    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props="label:'Item'"><button
    data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ToggleButton">Label</button></li>          
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: :]

I want this type of listView which include image tag, icon tag and a checkbox in each list item

Comment: How is your question about HTML and CSS related to android?

Comment: because i am using android environment in worklight

Comment: Some guys are really angry at your question. Remove the android tag, post the code of what you have done and make your question more specific, because no one will do the full work for you.

Comment: haha ok .well those guys are not aware about consequences ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Dojo documentation on ListItems for examples of adding built in options like icons.

dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/ListItem.html#dojox-mobile-listitem

For more complex layout, such as the larger title, small sub-title, and timestamp, you can use span tags and css.