# Custom ListView in IBM Worklight using Dojo

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am making custom list with the help of 
[this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/mobile/ListItem.html#dojox-mobile-listitem) tutorial.By the help of this tutorial i am able to add label and align it to right side and left side of list.But i find no option to align more label vertically at one side.Actually i want to implement like this

[image]

Two things i want to know

1. Label under other Label
2. Date under Label
3. Star Rating under Label

Comment: See if this questions gives you any hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498936/custom-listview-in-worklight-using-dojo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the HTML that edurocher provided and made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PPZjG/2/).

**HTML**

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.View">
     <h1 data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading" data-dojo-props='back:"Home", moveTo:"foo"'>Inbox</h1>

    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.RoundRectList">

        <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='variableHeight: true'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px" valign="top">
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-color: #cccc00; border-width:4px; width: 8px; height: 8px; -webkit-transform:  scale(0.7,1) rotate(45deg);"></div>
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="true"></input>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="font-weight: bold">Mike Cleron</div> <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: small">Ice Cream Social Announcement</span>
 <span style="font-weight: normal;font-size: small">- Like ice cream sandwiches? Like being social? </span>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" align="right" width="60px">
                        <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">Oct 18</div>
                        <div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Rating" data-dojo-props='image:"http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/checkout/demos/mobileGallery/images/star-orange.png",numStars:1,value:1'></div> 
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Load the widget parser and mobile base
require(["dojox/mobile/parser", "dojox/mobile/deviceTheme", "dojox/mobile/Rating", "dojox/mobile/compat", "dojox/mobile"],
  function (parser, deviceTheme) {

    // Parse the page for widgets!
    parser.parse();
});
```

[image: Dojo Custom List Item]

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is just add HTML content to your ListItem and use standard HTML/CSS to define the layout. Here is an example I put up quickly, using an HTML table, that looks like the example you sent:

```
    <li data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ListItem" data-dojo-props='variableHeight: true, selected: true'>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td style="padding: 5px" valign="top">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-color: #cccc00; border-width:4px; width: 8px; height: 8px; -webkit-transform:  scale(0.7,1) rotate(45deg);"></div>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="true"></input> 
            </td>
            <td>
            <div style="font-weight: bold">Mike Cleron</div>
            <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: small">Ice Cream Social Announcement</span>
            <span style="font-weight: normal;font-size: small">- Like ice cream sandwiches? Like being social? </span>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="right" width="60px">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">Oct 18</div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Rating" data-dojo-props='image:"images/star-orange.png",numStars:1,value:1'></div> 
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </li>
```

Hope this helps.